# Nginx with SEF URLs doesn't pass GET variables

Tags: nginx, get, request, php

I'm running nginx 1.6.1 and php-fpm 5.5.9. I have a setup to make SEF URLs. See the relevant part of the nginx configuration:

```
location / {
    # first try if the file or directory exists; if not, redirect to index.php
    # then index.php will see what to do based on the REQUEST_URI
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
}

# and just the basic php-fpm setup...
location ~* \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    # fastcgi.conf is as distributed, and doesn't contain anything special
    # anyway, the file is shown below
    include fastcgi.conf; 
}
```

Then, in index.php:

```
// Just for testing
var_dump($_SERVER);
var_dump($_GET);
```

Now, there are some different things I tried out:

```
My request         REQUEST_URI       GET is passed?
-----------------------------------------------
/index.php?test    /index.php?test   Yes
/index.php/?test   /index.php/?test  No
/?test             /?test            Yes
?test              (redirected to /?test)
/some-dir?test     /some-dir?test    No
/some-dir/?test    /some-dir/?test   No
```

That `/index.php/?test` doesn't work is not a big deal. Anyway, in the end we can remove the trailing slash using nginx. But why is the GET variable in the last two cases not passed?

Of course, I could do something with the REQUEST_URI in PHP using `parse_url`, but it would be much better if I could just access the variables using $_GET. What's going wrong?

---

For completeness, fastcgi.conf:

```
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
fastcgi_param  HTTPS              $https if_not_empty;

fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx/$nginx_version;

fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;

# PHP only, required if PHP was built with --enable-force-cgi-redirect
fastcgi_param  REDIRECT_STATUS    200;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Accidentally, I found the solution: the first location block (for `/`) was faulty. It shouldn't rewrite to `/index.php`, but to `/index.php$is_args$query_string`:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
}
```

From the [docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html):

> `$is_args` - “?” if a request line has arguments, or an empty string otherwise
>   `$args` - arguments in the request line

Now, for the sake of completeness, a trailing slash can also be removed, using this rewrite directive in the `server` block.

```
rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 permanent;
```